# Error in looping vb.net

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

```
    clustMember(0, 0) = "1,2,3,4,"
    clustMember(0, 1) = Nothing
    clustMember(0, 2) = "5,6,7,8,9,"
    clustMember(0, 3) = Nothing
    clustMember(1, 0) = "1,2,3,4,"
    clustMember(1, 1) = "5,6,7,8,9,"
    clustMember(1, 2) = Nothing
    clustMember(1, 3) = Nothing
    clustMember(2, 0) = "1,2,3,4,6,9,"
    clustMember(2, 1) = "5,7,8,"
    clustMember(2, 2) = Nothing
    clustMember(2, 3) = Nothing
    clustMember(3, 0) = Nothing
    clustMember(3, 1) = "1,2,3,4,5,6,8,"
    clustMember(3, 2) = "7,9,"
    clustMember(3, 3) = Nothing

    pmax = 3
    xini = 3

    For i As Integer = 1 To pmax - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To xini - 1
            If clustMember(i, j) <> Nothing Then
                lastSolution(i, j) = clustMember(i - 1, j)
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

I have problem when try to carried the data from clustMemBer to lastSolution. It is work fine when the value of j is 0 and 1. But when the value of j is 2, the value is clustMember can't move to lastSolution. When i trace the code, i found that when the value of j is 2, there are warning like this "the value of this expression may be incorrect. it could not be evaluated because j is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

Anybody know how to solve this problem?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are starting the outer loop at `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`, thus you are skipping the condition of `If clustMember(i, j) <> Nothing Then` for the first four items:

```
clustMember(0, 0) = "1,2,3,4,"
clustMember(0, 1) = Nothing
clustMember(0, 2) = "5,6,7,8,9,"
clustMember(0, 3) = Nothing
```

Secondly, you can only move back one item if you are not on the first item so check if this is the first time through the outer loop by changing your code to this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To pmax - 1
    For j As Integer = 0 To xini - 1
        If clustMember(i, j) <> Nothing Then
            If i > 0 Then
                lastSolution(i, j) = clustMember(i - 1, j)
            Else
                lastSolution(i, j) = clustMember(i, j)
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: actually it is my intention to skip first four array in lastSolution, because i have fill it with other value. I will try the second answer, i hope it will work fine.. thank you for your kind attention..